# Validation on a pre-populated form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

To set a default value in a form field in `symfony2`, I use the `rel` attribute combined with jQuery as beautifully explained [here](http://grasmash.com/article/using-jquery-prepopulate-inputs-default-values-clear-defaults-onclick-focus):

```
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array(
        'attr'=> array(
            'class'=>'prepopulate',
            'rel'=>'Enter a title here...',
        )
    ));
```

This works perfectly and gives the following:

---

[image]

---

As you can see, the field is pre-populated with "Enter a title here...".  If I validate the form as it is, validation does not take place as a default value is inserted (which makes sense).

I want to make sure the user customizes this field and does not just submit the form with the default value...

### **Is there a way to check if the field as the same value as the rel attribute?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this on the client side, and compare the rel attribute with the submitted data. If the value is the same, we clear the object:

```
$(function() {
    // When we submit the form
    $('form').submit(function() {

        //iterate over all the elements of the class "prepopulate"
        jQuery('.prepopulate').each(function(){

            //compare the values submitted vs rel attribute
            if( jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr('rel'))
                jQuery(this).val('');
        });
        return true; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeppers, that'll do it client-side. I thought you wanted a server-side option for the nut-jobs who have javascript turned off in their browsers. LOL But now that I think about it, if their javascript is turned off, they won't have prepopulated fields to begin with. So, you win. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

You could try this in your entity's annotation:

```
@Assert\Regex("/^(?!Enter a title here\.\.\.)/")
```

or even better:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^Enter a title here\.\.\.$/",
 *     match=false,
 *     message="Please enter a title."
 * )
 */
```

Comment: +1. Great trick @keyboardSmasher ! This has the disadvantage of repeating the code for every field. But you know, it works so it's good! Well done! If you're interested, I propose a javascript solution as this has the main advantage of iterating over each form fields. Thanks for your help!